# How to print-out a transposed 3D-array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, transpose

I have the following 3D array, which I need to print out as transposed one. It has 10 columns, 7 rows, adressed by (x,y) or (col, row)

```
    int[][][] map = {
    {{1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4}, {}, {}, {2, 2}, {}, {}, {}}, //first column
    {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}},
    {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}},
    {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}},
    {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {0}},
    {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}},
    {{}, {}, {}, {3, 4}, {}, {}, {}},
    {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}},
    {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}},
    {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}}
};
```

I tried switching the conditions, but it always crashes.

```
for (int threeD = 0; threeD < map.length; threeD++){
        for(int twoD = 0; twoD < map[threeD].length; twoD++){
            for (int oneD = 0; oneD < map[threeD][twoD].length; oneD++){

                          System.out.print(map[threeD][twoD][oneD]);
                 }
           System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Executing the code above gives this output:

```
    {1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4} {} {} {2 2} {} {} {}
    {} {} {} {} {} {} {}
    {} {} {} {} {} {} {}
    {} {} {} {} {} {} {}
    {} {} {} {} {} {} {0}
    {} {} {} {} {} {} {}
    {} {} {} {3 4} {} {} {}
    {} {} {} {} {} {} {}
    {} {} {} {} {} {} {}
    {} {} {} {} {} {} {}
```

The output i want should look as the following:

```
 {1 1 3 3 4 4 4 4} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}
 {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}
 {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}
 {2 2} {} {} {} {} {} {3  4} {} {} {}
 {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}
 {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}
 {} {} {} {} {0} {} {} {} {} {}
```

(I left the brackets to visualise it better  )

Comment: You should give an example of what your expected output would look like.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Uhm why are you using 3 dimensions? Actually, transposition usually applies to a NxM matrix, and transposed[i,j]=original[j,i]. Can you specify what you intend by transposition of a MxNxP matrix? transposed[i,j,k]=(what?)

Comment: If i understand this 3 dimensional array correctly, i want to transpose [i,j,k]= [j,i,k]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!

```
  for (int threeD = 0; threeD < map[0].length; threeD++){
    for(int twoD = 0; twoD < map.length; twoD++){
        for (int oneD = 0; oneD < map[twoD][threeD].length; oneD++){

                      System.out.print(map[twoD][threeD][oneD]);
             }
       System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```